# bind(): Operation not supported [core/socket.c line 230]

Tags: django, docker, nginx, uwsgi

I'm having a problem running django with uwsgi/nginx on docker. please what could be the issue?[uwsgi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu8P0.png)

I'm not quite sure what the issue is and I've tried googling the error, but nothing comes up. bellow is my uwsgi and nginx set up.

```
[uwsgi]
socket=/code/educa/uwsgi_app.sock
chdir= /code/educa/
module=educa.wsgi:application
master=true
chmod-socket=666
uid=www-data
gid=www-data
vacuum=true
```

```
# upstream for uWSGI

upstream uwsgi_app {
    server unix:/code/educa/uwsgi_app.sock;
}

server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   www.educaproject.com educaproject.com;
    error_log     stderr warn;
    access_log    /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi_app;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't know: the `educa` project in the question is for the book [Django 4 by Example](https://www.packtpub.com/product/django-4-by-example-fourth-edition/9781801813051)

---

I faced the exact problem when I was trying to dockerize the project using PyCharm terminal.
I managed to solve it by doing these:

1. In PyCharm terminal, in project root, run this command

   `chmod -R 777 ./`

   Example:

   `~/PycharmProjects/educa$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./`
2. In uwsgi.ini, change `chdir= /code/educa/` to `chdir= /code/`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the socket file and rebuild

Comment: thanks, already figured out a working solution.